# Validation rule for MS Access checkbox and email field

Tags: validation

I have a MS Access form with one EMAIL field and 2 checkboxes, let's call them A and B.
I need a validation rule to restrict entries.

1. Both A and B cannot be checked simultaneously.
2. If A is checked then EMAIL must have content.
3. If B is checked them EMAIL must be null.

This is the expression I use to accomplish #1 and it works fine but I can't figure #2 and #3.
([A]=False And [B]=False) Or ([A]=Not [B])

Answer (score 0):

```
     Private Sub A_AfterUpdate()
        If Me.A = -1 And IsNull(Me.emailadd) Then
        MsgBox "email address is required"
        Me.emailadd.SetFocus
        Me.A.Value = 0
        End If
        
        If Me.B = -1 Then
        MsgBox "B is checked, you have to  
        uncheck B before you can check A"
        Me.B.SetFocus
        Me.A.Value = 0
        End If
        
     End Sub


      Private Sub B_AfterUpdate()
        If Me.B = -1 And Not IsNull(Me.emailadd) Then
        MsgBox "email address must be empty"
        Me.emailadd.SetFocus
        Me.B.Value = 0
        End If
        
        If Me.A = -1 Then
        MsgBox "A is checked, you have to uncheck A before you can check B"
        Me.A.SetFocus
        Me.B.Value = 0
        End If
        
        End Sub





        Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
        If Me.A = -1 And IsNull(Me.emailadd) Then
        MsgBox "email address is required"
        Me.emailadd.SetFocus
        Me.A.Value = 0
        End If
        
        If Me.B = -1 Then
        MsgBox "B is checked, you have to  uncheck B before you can check A"
        Me.B.SetFocus
        Me.A.Value = 0
        End If
        
        If Me.B = -1 And Not IsNull(Me.emailadd) Then
        MsgBox "email address must be empty"
        Me.emailadd.SetFocus
        Me.B.Value = 0
        End If
        
        If Me.A = -1 Then
        MsgBox "A is checked, you have to  uncheck A before you can check B"
        Me.A.SetFocus
        Me.B.Value = 0
        End If
       End Sub
```